# Bootstrap col not inline

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, margin, inline, col

Hi I want to make layout with bootsrap, but the col can't display inline

```
<div class= "container">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-9 box1"
       <h1>Hello World</h1>
       </div>
      </div>

         <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-3 box2"
           <h1>Hi World</h1>
           </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

CSS

```
.box1 .box2 {
display: inline;
margin: 5px;
}
```

If I not add margin in CSS the box display inline, but when I add margin property the box2 go down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<div class="col-md-9 box1"` and `<div class="col-md-9 box2"` haven't got a `>` at their end.
If you want to display the 2 titles in the same row, you have to put them to the same row like :

`<div class= "container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-9 box1">
             <h1>Hello World</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 box2">
             <h1>Hi World</h1>
          </div>
       </div>
</div>`